# Beamer round blocks without fading

Tags: beamer, shading

I want to define a custom block in `beamer`.

Here are my definitions:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=White,bg=Red}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=Blue}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{lala}
fdsfdf
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How do I get rid of the fading effect between the title and the body?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly; if you want to get rid of the vertical shading that goes from the lower part of the title area to the upper part of the body area, you can use `\pgfdeclareverticalshading` to change the vertical shading `bmb@transition` (the original definition can be found in `beamerbaseboxes.sty`):

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=White,bg=Red}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=Blue}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareverticalshading[lower.bg,upper.bg]{bmb@transition}{200cm}{%
  color(0pt)=(lower.bg); color(4pt)=(lower.bg); color(4pt)=(upper.bg)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{lala}
fdsfdf
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Oh, that is good to know, Gonzalo. Is it similarly possible to get rid of the shadow's shading (with [shadow=true]) as well?

Comment: @Daniel: I think I don't understand your question, do you mean to eliminate the shadow when using the `shadow=true` option?

Comment: No, I mean to have the shadow, but not a shaded shadow :-) (that is, the complete shadow should be just one grey value). Background: The softened shadows induce long processing times when printing on a PS printer, which is an issue for printing lecture notes in large quantities.

Comment: @Daniel: Ah; in this case, you'll have to change the vertical shading `bmb@shadow` and the radial shadings `bmb@shadowball` and `bmb@shadowballlarge`; the original definitions are in `beamerbaseboxes.sty`.

Answer (score 0):

With the upcoming version v0.3 of the tcolorbox inner theme, you can switch off the shading like this:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=White,bg=Red}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=Blue}

\useinnertheme[shadow,rounded,shaded=false]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{lala}
fdsfdf
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]